# Flutter FutureBuilder exceptions: add default behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app I use `FutureBuilder` extensively and I would like a generic behaviour when one of them fails. I am trying this setup

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //imp line need to be added first

  FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
    print("*** CAUGHT FROM FRAMEWORK ***");
    await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(details);
  };

  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(new MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
            child: Center(child: new LaunchWidget()))
      ),
    );
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print("**** ZONED EXCEPTION ****");
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace);
  });
```

With this setup any failing `FutureBuilder` won't go in any of the two error handlers.
The only way to do something is to use

```
FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: failingFuture(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => (snapshot.hasError) handle() : doSomething()
```

is there any less verbose way to handle this?

Comment: I'm also struggeling with this. And we just had a production error that didn't get reported due to this. Did you find any solution?

There's the debugRethrowError, but that only works in debug mode: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder/debugRethrowError.html

Currently, I expect to add a wrapper around the FutureBuilder and report the error through there :/

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up doing this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Wrap builder to report errors
class FutureBuilder2<T> extends FutureBuilder<T> {
  FutureBuilder2({
    Key? key,
    Future<T>? future,
    T? initialData,
    required AsyncWidgetBuilder<T> builder,
  }) : super(
            key: key,
            future: future,
            initialData: initialData,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<T> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                FlutterError.reportError(FlutterErrorDetails(
                    exception: snapshot.error!, stack: snapshot.stackTrace));
              }
              return builder(context, snapshot);
            });
}
```

You'll have to remember to use FutureBuilder2, but it seems to be the best that I could come up with. Also, properly name it better ;)

If anybody knows of any drawbacks when doing this, please let me know